# Xamarin Forms Maps Charging

Tags: xamarin.forms, maps

In Xamarin Forms For Android App. When users open the application. Does google charge my account just for opening Google Map?
I read their doc but that was not clear to me. I appreciate it if somebody explains it to me.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, Google Maps will charge a certain fee when requests for the application reach a certain number. It'll remind you to create a billing account. Here is the [tutorial​](https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/) about the pricing scales that you can refer to.

Comment: so if I develop an app and use google map just for showing map and not calling api for geocoding. it cost me alot. maybe i must switch to OpenStreetMap or another map providers

Comment: Yes, I think so.